# Building Workspace has encountered an issue

Tags: android, eclipse, ide, application-error

After unexpected shutdown of Eclipse IDE, and on restarting it gave the following error log:

```
 Errors occurred during the build.
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (2).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (2).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (2).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (2).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (2).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (2).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (2).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (2).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (2).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (2).
```

Eclipse shut down automatically frequently. Please help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

(I don't have enought reputation to just comment yet, so I'll answer here.)

It's hard to tell, but my guess is that most probably you are getting an OutOfMemory error or similar error/exception, that is making your eclipse crash in the first place. A few questions to orientate the issue:

- what version of eclipse and android SDK are you using?
- what is your platform?
- how much physical memory do you have?
- have you tried monitoring your system while running eclipse (for example, with "top" in linux), to see if you are running out of memory or any other resources?
- do you have any non-standard/non-usual plugins installed? If so, have you tried removing them?
- Do you have a very large number of projects/files in your workspace?
- The errors you show are all android related. Have you tried running a copy of the same eclipse but without the android plugins? Have you tried switching workspaces?
- Are you running eclipse with any special vmargs? (see also [this article from eclipse wiki on memory arguments](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F))
- Android-wise, does this happend when doing something in particular with the emulator or a physical phone?

It would be great if you could edit your question to include this information.